# Couchbase Query not working as expected

Tags: java, sql, couchbase, sql++

using Couchbase 4.1 I have the following document structure

```
"bucketName": {
                "UserId": "user1",
                "skillSet": {
                    "punchPower": 1,
                    "kickPower": 1,
                    "specialPower": "Extreme programmer"
                },
                "id": "GameUser_XXX1D",
                "timestamp": 1464935606358
            }
```

I want a query which will return me back the most recent timestamp and the total number of all matches this is what I have.

```
select count(timestamp) as users, timestamp from bucketName where id like 'GameUser__%' AND 
skillSet.specialPower = 'Extreme Programmer' AND 
skillSet.kickPower = 1 AND 
skillSet.punchPower = 1 AND 
timestamp BETWEEN $sometimeIPassHere AND $sometimeIPassHere 
ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1;
```

This returns back the correct number of users as I expect but the timestamp that is being returned is incorrect the oldest timestamp is being returned as if the `desc` is not being considered in my query. I've tried removing, and applying `asc`which also returned the same result.

How can I resolve this incorrect query result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by applying the `max()` method.

```
select max(timestamp), count(timestamp) as users, timestamp from bucketName where id like 'GameUser__%' AND 
skillSet.specialPower = 'Extreme Programmer' AND 
skillSet.kickPower = 1 AND 
skillSet.punchPower = 1 AND 
timestamp BETWEEN $sometimeIPassHere AND $sometimeIPassHere 
ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1;
```